# Do I have to redo my meta analysis?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, percentage

I did a meta analysis of percentages using metamean in RStudio. Should I have used metaprop instead? For the SD argument in meta mean I used the SD for the binomial distribution.

Comment: You might like to post this on the list dedicated to meta-analysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// Mention you already posted here.

Answer (score 1):

If your outcome is binary (1/0), and you are interested in proportions, you should use the binomial likelihood. Therefore, yes, you should re-do your meta-analysis. Avoid the double-arcsine transformation:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1591

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I redo it or do I have to? Are my results invalid or just suboptimal?

Comment: Wouldn't I be correct that my result would merely be suboptimal since my observations numbered in the hundreds, and the normal distribution approximates binomial for sufficiently large n?

Comment: My reading of R Studio's documentation regarding metamean and metaprop suggests that effectively all I did is use metaprop with raw proportion data. By putting the binomial standard deviation into metamean, I calculated the appropriate standard error for each study's proportion-valued effect size. From there, metamean calculated an appropriate D-L inverse variance weight for each study's proportion valued effect size and therefore calculated an appropriate random effects average.